# I'm unable to change network interfaces' metrics in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, interface, metrics

I am trying to change the priority of network interfaces on my server using `ifmetric`. When I execute the command it looks like it worked (exit code 0), but it simply won't affect the interfaces - in `ifconfig` it shows `Metric:1` for all interfaces.

Same result when I insert `up ifmetric wlan1 2` in `/etc/network/interfaces` under the correct section. Rebooting doesn't help either.

I use Raspbian Jessie Lite.

Answer (score 1):

As per the ifmetric [man page](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifmetric/ifmetric.8.xml):

> ifmetric is a Linux tool for setting the metrics of all **IPv4 routes** attached to a given network interface at once

It does not change the metric of the interface itself, but instead the metric of the routes reachable out of the interface. This is useful if you have multiple interfaces with a route to the same destination.

You can view the metrics of your routes with the `route -n` command.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how can I change the metric of an interface?